# How to paginate associated records?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, associations, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

`Products belongsToMany Categories` and `Categories hasMany Products`, inside my `Product` view I'm showing a list of all it's categories but I want to paginate or limit these results.

My current code on `ProductsController` is:

```
$product = $this->Products
    ->findBySlug($slug_prod)
    ->contain(['Metas', 'Attachments', 'Categories'])
    ->first();

$this->set(compact('product'));
```

I know I need to set `$this->paginate()` to paginate something but I can't get it working to paginate the categories inside the product. I hope you guys can understand me.

UPDATE: Currently I have this going on:

```
$product = $this->Products->findBySlug($slug_prod)->contain([
              'Metas',
              'Attachments',
              'Categories' => [
                'sort' => ['Categories.title' => 'ASC'],
                'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
                  return $q->order(['Categories.title' => 'ASC'])->limit(6);
                }
              ]
            ])->first();
```

The limit works but I don't know how to paginate yet

Comment: What does "another controller" have to do with any of this, to me it sounds as if all you want to do is to display a records associated data with pagination?

Comment: I think you are right, I changed my code, can you check again please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paginator doesn't support paginating associations, you'll have to read the associated records manually in a separate query, and paginate that one, something along the lines of this:

```
$product = $this->Products
    ->findBySlug($slug_prod)
    ->contain(['Metas', 'Attachments'])
    ->first();

$categoriesQuery = $this->Products->Categories
    ->find()
    ->innerJoinWith('Products', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($product) {
        return $query->where([
            'Products.id' => $product->id,
        ]);
    })
    ->group('Categories.id');

$paginationOptions = [
    'limit' => 6,
    'order' => [
        'Categories.title' => 'ASC'
    ]
];

$categories = $this->paginate($categoriesQuery, $paginationOptions);

$this->set(compact('product', 'categories'));
```

Then in your view template you can display your `$product` and separately paginate `$categories` as usual.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helper> Paginator](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

Comment: I thought about doing this way but I get another error, the SQL is wrong in this case: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Product.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: SQL is looking for `Product.id = :c0 AND Product.id = ProductsCategories.product_id)`, the second one is right but I think the first one is wrong and I don't know why because there isn't a condition

Comment: I got it working, it was a typo. It should be like you said Products.id instead of Product.id. Thank you very much!