# CakePHP 3.x paginate associated model with relationship

Tags: model, cakephp-3.0, relationship, pagination

I have a model Categories wish is associated with Channels model (belongsToMany). 
In view Category i have many Related Channels and i want paginate them. 
Table Channels don't have category_id i used table category_channels for relations.

If i use this code:

```
 $category = $this->Categories->get($id, ['contain' => ['Users', 'Chanels']]);

 $this->paginate = [
          'contain' => ['Chanels', 'Users'],
          'sortWhitelist' => [
              'Chanels.title'
        ]
 ];
 $this->set('category', $this->paginate($category));
```

I have error:
Error: Call to undefined method App\Model\Entity\Category::alias()

I have tried another code:

```
$query = $this->Categories->find('all')
            ->where(['Categories.id' => $id])
            ->contain(['Users', 'Chanels' => function($q) {
                    return $q
                        ->order('created ASC')
                        ->limit(5);
          }]);

$category = $this->paginate($query);

$this->set(compact('category'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['category']);
```

It's work i have 5 channels in Related Channels but pagination doesn't work!
How is possible to paginate Channels? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paginate associated records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901181/how-to-paginate-associated-records)

Comment: Thank You very much man! 
You saved my life! 2 days I'm trying to solve this problem.