# cakephp 3 pagination for cotain tables [ One to Many]

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I want to get pagination for Poems of members. Member have a lot of poems. I get only all result of this member poems. Can I paginate the Poems ?

```
$member = $this->Members->get($id, [
            'contain' => [
              'Poems'=>function($q){
                return $q->where(['status'=>1,'is_deleted'=>0]);

              }
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paginate associated records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901181/how-to-paginate-associated-records)

Comment: Or you're trying to do pagination of all of the poems regardless of tho they are from? It's not entirely clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish.