# Sorting on nested relationship

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-4.x

I have the following relationship:

```
Rounds hasMany Results
Results belongsTo Drivers
```

`Results` are shown on `Rounds`'s view page: `rounds/view/{id}`. I want to sort `Results` based on `Drivers.name`.

This is my `RoundsController::view` method:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'sortableFields' => [
            'Results.Drivers.name',
        ]
    ];

    $round = $this->Rounds->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Championships' => ['Teams'], 'Tracks', 'Results' => ['Drivers', 'Constructors']],
    ]);

    $this->set(compact('round'));
}
```

And in my `rounds/view.ctp` file, I have this:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('Results.Drivers.name', __('Driver')); ?>
```

However, no matter what I change, it doesn't sort by driver name. Also, when I click it multiple times, the direction stays `asc`.

Why is it not working?

Comment: First things first, you cannot paginate with `get()`, as it will query only 1 single record. Please make sure that you are posting the correct code that you're actually using.

Comment: This is the exact code I am using. Let me see if I can get it working with a different query and I'll let you know.

Comment: This code can't work for multiple reasons, generally pagination will only work when you actually invoke it, eg make use of the `pagination()` method. Only configuring that property won't do anything. Secondly, associations cannot be paginated with the built in paginator, you'd have to query them separately to paginate them, see for example **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901181/how-to-paginate-associated-records**. Lastly, sortable fields cannot be nested, such thing doesn't exist on SQL level, you can only sort on main table columns, joined table columns, or computed columns.

Answer (score -1):

Like @ndm mentioned, your code is showing only one specific Round. **View** method/function is receiving an **$id** arg, this $id is related to the round id you want to show in view page.

You can not order this (you can do it but it doesnt make sense) because you are receiving only one Round, and it doesnt make sense to order only one row.

This **view** method is usually used with this goal: show individual/personal information about an Entity (Round entity in your case). Please, note I use the word USUALLY.

I think you could use the **index** method for this purpose (this method/function is usually used to list entities from a model and its association data). You could create a new method/function for your porpuse as well if you already are using **index** method for another goal.

I suggest something like this, assuming you will use the index function:

```
public function index()
{
    $rounds = $this->Rounds->find('all')
                          ->contain([
                                     'Championships' => ['Teams'], 
                                     'Tracks', 
                                     'Results' => [
                                                    'Constructors'
                                                    [ 
                                                      'Drivers' => function (Query $q) {
                                                        return $q->order('Drivers.name');;
} 
                                                    ] 
                                                    
                                                  ]
                                    ]);

    $rounds= $this->paginate($rounds);
    $this->set(compact('rounds'));
}
```

You could pass conditions into the contain or do the same into paginate method. I always use the first (just preferences).

NOTE: this code may not work, it is an idea of what you could do.

Finders documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data

Passing conditions to contains: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

Comment: I'm not ordering a round. I'm attempting to order results for that round. The view method can be used to view an object and it's relations. I am viewing A round (object) and it's results (it's relations) and trying to order those relations.